# Markov Clustering Algorithm

Tags: javascript, cluster-analysis, markov

I've been working through the following example of the details of the Markov Clustering algorithm:

http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/classes/CS595D-2009winter/MCL_Presentation2.pdf

I feel like I have accurately represented the algorithm but I am not getting the same results that this guide, at least, was getting for that input.

Current code is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/methodin/CtGJ9/

I am not sure if perhaps I have just missed a small fact or just need a small tweak somewhere for this but I have tried a few variations including:

1. Swapping the Inflation/Expansion
2. Checking for equality based on a precision
3. Removing the normalization (since the original guide did not require it, although the official MCL documentation states to normalize the matrix on every pass)

All of these have returned the same result - the node only influences itself.

I've even found a similar algorithm implementation in VB:
http://mcl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/17748#MCL%2fMCL%2fMatrix.vb

And my code seems to match up with the exception of their numbering (600 - distance for instance).

This is the expansion function

```
// Take the (power)th power of the matrix effectively multiplying it with
// itself pow times
this.matrixExpand = function(matrix, pow) {
    var resultMatrix = [];
    for(var row=0;row<matrix.length;row++) {
        resultMatrix[row] = [];
        for(var col=0;col<matrix.length;col++) {
            var result = 0;
            for(var c=0;c<matrix.length;c++)
                result += matrix[row][c] * matrix[c][col];
            resultMatrix[row][col] = result;
        }
    }
    return resultMatrix;
};
```

And this is the inflation function

```
// Applies a power of X to each item in the matrix
this.matrixInflate = function(matrix, pow) {
    for(var row=0;row<matrix.length;row++) 
        for(var col=0;col<matrix.length;col++)
            matrix[row][col] = Math.pow(matrix[row][col], pow);
};
```

And finally the main passthru function

```
// Girvan–Newman algorithm
this.getMarkovCluster = function(power, inflation) {
    var lastMatrix = [];

    var currentMatrix = this.getAssociatedMatrix();
    this.print(currentMatrix);        
    this.normalize(currentMatrix);  

    currentMatrix = this.matrixExpand(currentMatrix, power);    
    this.matrixInflate(currentMatrix, inflation);                               
    this.normalize(currentMatrix);

    while(!this.equals(currentMatrix,lastMatrix)) {
        lastMatrix = currentMatrix.slice(0);

        currentMatrix = this.matrixExpand(currentMatrix, power);                
        this.matrixInflate(currentMatrix, inflation);         
        this.normalize(currentMatrix);            
    }
    return currentMatrix;
};
```

Comment: the jsfiddle link seems to be broken, is your implementation still available somewhere? thanks!

Comment: Strange. I wonder where it went? Here is a gist with the code: https://gist.github.com/methodin/1573728

Comment: Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/NqWqWe?editors=101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is correct. The example is just wrong.

The three result matrices on the "Repeat steps 5 and 6 until a steady state is reached (convergence)" slide are the results of ONLY performing inflation.

To clarify some points about the algorithm.

1. Expantion then inflation.
2. Precision is an important factor. The equations can never lead to convergence mathematically. Its the limited precision of floating point operations on cpus that cause some items in the matrix to become zero rather than infinitly small numbers. In fact the official implementation uses a cutoff value to eliminate a certain amount of items per column to speed up convergence and improve the time complexity of the algorithm. In the original thesis the author analized the effect of this and concluded that the cutoff gives the same result in practice as a slight increase of the inflation parameter.
3. Normalization is an integral part of the inflation step, read the equation in that guide again.

Regarding your code.

1. array.slice creates a shallow copy but this not important in your case since you create a new array in matrixExpand.
2. Your implementation of matrixExpand ignores the pow variable, and always does a power of 2.

The result where there are all ones in the first row is expected, which is interpreted as all elements are in the same cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I assumed the example was probably showing something else but couldn't identify what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Using currentMatrix.slice to clone a matrix looks suspicious.  It's a shallow clone, and since you are mutating, that may spell trouble.

The use of round also looks a little strange, as there's no mention of rounding as a part of the normalization step in that powerpoint presentation.

Comment: Added a copy method to run the full copy but it still returns the same result. Removing the round gives a different result however it's just 0.99999999877 instead of 1 and 0.00004 instead of 0 so effectively the same result. I find it odd that after the first iteration (before the while loop) the matrices are identical to the powerpoint but after one iteration they are completely different.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, without looking more closely at the algorithm and working it by hand, is that the equal() method you've written doesn't look quite right.  It's not comparing with Math.abs, which I had expected to see.

Comment: Tried an abs on each section and the overall result, both of which didn't affect the result. Really quite odd! I'm wondering if perhaps the example I was going off of was using different data in the various sections.

Comment: I implemented most of it myself without looking at your code.  http://jsfiddle.net/qTZnw/  Seem to have a similar problem.  While at first the values look like they're going to converge to the numbers given, they quickly end up with all the probability weight in the first row.  Is that what's happening for you?